# What is the best way to develop and test cache in a Ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, web-applications

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to start "to code" the cache system.

I am working on *localhost* in *development* mode. I heard that working in *development* mode it is possible to face some "confusing" errors. **Why? What is the best way to that cache?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need a clear mind.

In `development.rb`, change this:

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Then work and test. It will write the cached pages in `/public`, and fragments in `/tmp/cache`

Here are great articles to understand caching in Rails:

http://broadcastingadam.com/2012/07/advanced_caching_revised